# Group posts by attachment meta key

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to group posts by meta key. So far I am able to show all the posts with the meta key ('grouping') but with this it is listing the grouping with each post.

What I want to achieve is list the grouping as a heading, then list all of the posts with that grouping under it.

For example:

### Christmas

- post1
- post2
- post3

### Contemporary

- post4
- post5
- post6
- post7

### Jazz

- post8
- post9

...and so on. The 'Christmas', 'Contemporary' and 'Jazz' are the 'grouping' meta values.

Here is my current loop:

```
<ul>

<?php $args = array(
// 'post_parent' => $post->ID,
'post_type'   => 'attachment',
'post_mime_type' => array('audio/midi', 'zip'),
'numberposts' => -1,
'meta_key'      => 'grouping',
'orderby'      => 'meta_value',
'order'    => 'ASC',

);


$posts = get_posts($args);

if( $posts ): ?>

<ul>
    
<?php foreach( $posts as $post ): 
    
    setup_postdata( $post );

    $grouping = get_field('grouping'); 
    
    ?>

    <?php if ($grouping == $grouping ) { ?>

        <h2><?php echo $grouping; ?></h2>

    <li>


        <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
    </li>

<?php } ?>

<?php endforeach; ?>

</ul>

<?php wp_reset_postdata(); ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

This returns something like this:

#### Christmas

- Fantasia 2

#### Christmas

- Fantasia 1

#### Christmas

- We Three Kings

Which I totally understand. I just can't seem to figure out how to group the posts by the 'grouping' meta key. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is really more of a php/html question as this problem comes up outside of Wordpress. What you want to do is check the current meta name against the previous one, and if it's different, then you echo the header. You're already pulling all the posts you need in one go, so it's something like:

```
$currentGroup = "";
foreach ($posts as $post) {
  setup_postdata($post);
  $grouping = get_field('grouping');
  if ($grouping != $currentGroup) {
    if ($currentGroup != "") {
      echo "</ul>";
    }
    echo "<h2>" . $grouping . "</h2><ul>";
  }
  $currentGroup = $grouping;
  echo "<li><a href='" . the_permalink() . "'>" . the_title() . "</a></li>";
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Perfecto. I just needed to null the group value and add a second nested loop. Thank you so much.